# Textfile processing in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Access 2016: My goal is to simply read in a text file using Access VBA. I used the FileOpen function, {FileOpen(1, "TESTFILE", OpenMode.Input)}, but it does not prompt for the arguments as soon as I type "FileOpen(" and I get an immediate compile error as soon as the statement is complete. Tried using the FileSystemObject OpenTextFile method but it doesn't compile either (I did add the Runtime Scripting library to my references list). Ideas?

Comment: I seem to get faster, better, and more answers when I [include just a little snippet of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). probably because it is much easier for others to copy/paste/modify rather than writing an example from scratch, and programmers can more generally read the code to quickly see the problem regardless of what language the question was written in.

Comment: I'm stumped by `FileOpen()`. That function exists in .Net, but .Net != VBA.  For VBA, have you considered [Open Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

There are two main ways to read text files in VBA -- `Scripting.FileSystemObject` (a.k.a. text streams) and `Open`.

Although the code is a little uglier looking, I prefer using `Open` ... `As #` for a few reasons:

- Performance on file reads/writes is usually a little better
- Binary/Random operations are much easier to do
- For large reads, text streams are kinda flaky

Here are two different ways of doing the same thing:

```vb
Public Function GetFileContentsByLine(fileName As String) As String
  Dim ff As Long
  Dim thisLine As String
  ff = FreeFile

  Open fileName For Input As #ff
    Do Until EOF(ff)
      Input #ff, thisLine
      GetFileContentsByLine = GetFileContentsByLine & thisLine & vbCrLf
    Loop
  Close #ff
End Function
```

This version assumes that you want to go through one line at a time (which is a normal way to read the text file). If you wanted to read the entire contents in one go, it's not the fastest way to do it, but it gives you the flexibility of being able to react to the individual lines as they are pulled in.

For very large text files, you may run into `Out of memory` errors. This happens because of how strings are added to other strings in memory. For typical situations, though, you shouldn't run into any problems.

```vb
Public Function GetFileContents(fileName As String) As String
  Dim ff As Long
  Dim thisLine() As Byte
  ff = FreeFile

  Open fileName For Binary As #ff
    ReDim thisLine(LOF(ff))
    Get #ff, , thisLine
  Close #ff
  GetFileContents = StrConv(thisLine, vbUnicode)
End Function
```

This version figures out the size of the file, grabs the whole thing in one large block, and then stores the contents as a string. It's faster than the first way, but it's not what people normally mean when they talk about "reading text files."

Comment: The Open with Input loop works well for my purposes. Thx!

Comment: Great!  Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample function of how to read in a file and return the contents. You will need a reference to Runtime Scripting library

```vb
Function SampleReadFile() As String
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim txtStream As TextStream
Dim strContents As String

'create file system object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'get the text stream of the file
    Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile("Path to my file")
    'read the contents into a string
    strContents = txtStream.ReadAll

    'close the text stream
    txtStream.Close
    'free the memory
    Set txtStream = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    'return the contents of the file
    SampleReadFile = strContents
End Function
```